# Invoke required field validator through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a non standard submit button in my ASP.NET form along the lines of.

```
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="this.blur();SubmitForm();"><span>Submit</span></a>
```

Due to this, my required field validator is not being invoked on the client side. How can the required field validator be invoked through Javascript?

Alternatively is there a better way to accomplish what I am attempting to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use in built client side function named `Page_ClientValidate` for this.Check out the following code snippet for the reference

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ClientSide_Validation.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="ClientSide_Validation" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function performCheck() {

            if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Please enter some value"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valReq" ControlToValidate="txtbox1" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <input type="button" id="btnValidate" value="Submit" onclick="performCheck()" />
        <a href="#" onclick="performCheck();">Validate</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will create problem when you have multiple validation group on same page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11548526/779158 found problem answer here  for validation group as well.

Answer (score 9):

`Page_ClientValidate` triggers validation for all validators on the form and as @gilly3 shows out you can also validate them all by looping the collection and calling `ValidatorValidate(validator)`

However if you want to validate just one particular validator then you need to call `ValidatorValidate(validator)` for just one item.

The validator argument needs to be a DOM object which can be tricky to get because the element ID might end up quite different than you specified in the mark up if you are using master pages or user controls.

e.g.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCampaignStartDate" runat="server" .../>
```

becomes

```
<span id="cph_0_rfvCampaignFile" ...>
```

I got around this in one of my projects by using a jQuery selector like this

```
ValidatorValidate($('[id$="rfvCampaignFile"]').get(0));
```

ASP.NET only prefixes the IDs to create a unique name I could use `id$=` part of the selector to match any IDs ending in `"rfvCampaignFile"` since I wrote the website I know it won't clash with other controls. Finally I use `.get(0)` to return the DOM object reference to the first (and only in my case) DOM object matched.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [client side api for ASP.Net validators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside).  All the validators on the page are exposed in an `Array` via `Page_Validators`.  You can call `ValidatorValidate(validator)` on a single validator to invoke it.  So, to invoke all validators on the page you could:

```
Page_Validators.forEach(ValidatorValidate);
```

By the way, to use `Array.forEach` in older browsers [you'll need to extend Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach#Compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery then set a ASP.NET control `ClientIDMode = "Static"` and you can make your code easier to read as:

```
ValidatorValidate($('#MyControl'));
```

or something very similar.