# Working RequiredFieldValidator along with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have multiple RequiredFieldValidator such as:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtbox1" 
            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required Field" SetFocusOnError="True" 
            ValidationGroup="validator1" CssClass="validator" />
```

Linked to this button:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnNext1" Text="Next Page" CssClass="btn" ValidationGroup="validator1" />
```

Along with some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    function nextPage1() {

        $( "#divFirstPage" ).hide("fade");
        $( "#divSecondPage" ).show("fade");
        $( "#<%=btnNext1.ClientID%>" ).hide();
        $( "#<%=btnNext2.ClientID%>" ).show();
        $( "#<%=btnPrevious1.ClientID%>" ).show();
    };
    $( "#<%=btnNext1.ClientID%>" ).click(function() {
        nextPage1();
        return false;
    });
    $( "#divSecondPage" ).hide();
    $( "#divThirdPage" ).hide();
    $( "#<%=btnNext2.ClientID%>" ).hide();
    $( "#<%=btnPrevious1.ClientID%>" ).hide();
    $( "#<%=btnPrevious2.ClientID%>" ).hide();
});
</script>
```

But the javascript gets executed before the validations, so id need to execute the validations **before** the javascript

Comment: So you want to execute the validators **before** the code in the `nextPage1` function??

Comment: yes, sorry for not making that clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to validate your form before executing javascript code

Try something like this:

```
$( "#<%=btnNext1.ClientID%>" ).click(function() {
    var val = Page_ClientValidate();
    if(!val) {
        return false;
    }
    nextPage1();
    return true;
});
```

Optionally if you want to specify a custom `ValidationGroup`, you can use the following code:

```
Page_ClientValidate('your group name');
```

Comment: ok so the validators are being triggered but i got a new problem, it wont let me go onto the second page. i believe that this is because Page_ClientValidate() is also checking the textboxes on the other pages, in which i cant access

Comment: Remember to `return true;` in your script. `Page_ClientValidate` validates the page, if you did not specify a group, then it will validate the whole page, if you want to restrict to just validate few controls, group them using the `ValidationGroup` property and call the validation like this:  `Page_ClientValidate('groupName')`

Comment: This should work, try with only one validator in your page just te confirm it is validating correctly. Then ensure the form is _actually valid_ according to the validators configuration