# Deleting data using confirmation window popup in ASP.NET and with RequiredFieldValidator

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using the following code to delete records from database using confirmation.

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text_delete" Width="70%" Height="60px" ValidationGroup="del" CssClass="textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="required_desc" CssClass="validator" ValidationGroup="del" ControlToValidate="text_delete" ErrorMessage="Reason Required" runat="server">Reason Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="button_delete" CssClass="button" ValidationGroup="del" Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClientClick="Confirm()" OnClick="button_delete_Click" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete this data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>
```

**C#**

```
protected void button_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
    if (confirmValue == "Yes")
    {
        // Delete the data
    }
    if (confirmValue == "No")
    {
        // Do not delete data
    }
}
```

But here i want the user to enter the reason to delete in textbox first and only after that the confirm popup should appear. Even though i am using a required field validator the validator is fired only after the popup window. How can i fire the validator first and only if the reason is entered the popup window for delete confirmation should appear. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke the required field validation within a script using Page_ClientValidate(), or Page_ClientValidate("group name") if you want to be more specific.

```
if(Page_ClientValidate()){
     ....popup confirmation code
     ....
}
```

[Working RequiredFieldValidator along with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548383/working-requiredfieldvalidator-along-with-javascript/11548526#11548526)